# Facebook Like/Unlike gives error message

Tags: ios, facebook

I am building an application which implements Facebook. Through this application I can like and comment on a post. I am fetching Home feeds for the logged in user. Now for Like operation I am using the graph API :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID/likes?&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

with `HTTPMethod: POST`

Here, the `POST_ID` is the `ID` I am getting for each feed and the access token of the logged in user.

Now in most of the cases I can like the feed using this API. But some posts don't have Like Connections. How do I know which feed has a like connection & which does not.

Now coming to Unlike. For Unlike operation I am using the graph API :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID/likes?&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

with `HTTPMethod: DELETE`

I can unlike some posts or feeds using this API. But for some I get an error message. In that case i am using for example:

This is the
`POST_ID = 12345_67890`. When I get error message for this I am using the 67890 as the `POST_ID` in this case & I am getting success to unlike a post/feed.

Again in using this `67890` as `POST_ID` gives error in some cases & in that case I am using OBJECT_ID if exists in the feed I am receiving. And I am getting true response in some cases.

But in rest of the cases I can't find any solution for Like & Unlike of a feed/post in Facebook.

Waiting for positive reply.

Comment: In general apps can only delete stuff that was created using the same app. I don't know exactly if that applies for unliking of posts as well - could you check if the behavior is different for post that where liked using your app before and posts that where liked any other way (directly on facebook.com, other app) to either confirm or dismiss?

Comment: Posts that were made from the app can be successfully liked & unliked from the app. But when I like a post created by some other person from   facebook or other apps. Like is successful but when I try to unlike these posts from my app that were previously liked from my app but created by others from facebook or other mobile/apps I get the error message.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using correct post_id of feed than it will never produce any error while liking/disliking post on facebook by following code
if do you want to like than change HTTPMethod to POST otherwise set DELETE for dislike. there is no need of accesstoken to call this api.if you are using so it will not produce any error

```
     [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/likes",@"Post_id"] parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"DELETE" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"ok!! %@",result);
    }
}];
```